# Perl: How to remove spaces and blank lines in one pass

Tags: perl

I have got 2 perl scripts, first one removes blank lins from a file and the second one removes all spaces inside a file. I wonder, if it's possible to connect both of these regular expressions inside 1 script?

---

For spaces, i have used this regsub: `$str =~ tr/ //d;`
and for Blank lines, I have used this regexp

```
while (<$file>) {
    if (/\S/){
    print $new_file $_; }}
```

---

Comment: `perl -nlwe 'tr/ //d; print if length' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be really easy: just add `tr/ //d` before the if line.

Note: It will remove lines containing spaces only, too. If you want to keep them (but transliterated to empty lines), insert the transliteration before the print line.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to trim the end of the line that contains space, 
you might want it to work like this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\s*$/\n/' f1 f2 f3   #UNIX file format
perl -pi -e 's/\s*$/\r\n/' f1 f2 f3   #DOS file format
```